# Vue.js using vue-resource populating array in data()

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm having trouble populating an array in data(). I'm simply pulling from a users JSON object(10 users), which is the same structure as [randomapi](https://randomuser.me/)

```
    <template>
  <div class='row'>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="u in users">
        Name : {{u.name}}
        <br>
        Email: {{u.email}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

When the data is received, i loop through and populate a resultsArray, when it finishes, the users[] is equal to the resultsArray

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        users: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getUsers() {
        this.$http.get('./playground/users.json')
        .then(response => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
          const resultArray = []
          for(let key in data){
            resultArray.push(data[key])
          }
          this.users = resultArray
          console.log(this.users)
        })
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.getUsers()
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image]

It's printing the following:
Name :
Email:

JSON object
[image]

Comment: So, your question is that, even after API call finished and got result in resultArray, coping process of array data in resultArray to `this.users` does not work, right?

Comment: right yes. It pushes to resultsArray, with 10 users, but it doesnt seem to transfer to names [ ]

Comment: I checked Random User Generator you mentioned. I would like to know what kind of structure does `data` have. Can you show me that?

Comment: nothing is set or passed in App.vue, its a pretty basic app, just trying to learn. I updated the post with a picture of the JSON

Comment: Thanks! How about resultArray. Does it have successfully a copy of `data`?

Comment: Yes the resultArray has got 10 users, but as soon as i make this.users equal to it, it on has 10 also. I will update with a screenshot in console.

Comment: How about abandon using `resultArray` as a copy? Just clean up the content of `this.users` before making API call, and then pushing the response data directly into `this.users`. Vue.js reactive watches the change of data with observer, so that direct push into `users` might fire the update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154029/discussion-between-johnn5er-and-izumisy).